# Why should I use EXEC after the creating temp tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I created 2 temp tables `#ClientsCountForDoctor` and `#DeathCount`:

```
CREATE TABLE #ClientsCountForDoctor (DoctorCode int, Clients int)   

SELECT 
   Personal.[DoctorCode], Count(Clients.[ClientCode]) AS [Count-Код клиента]
FROM 
   Personal 
INNER JOIN 
   (Clients INNER JOIN MedicalCard ON Clients.[ClientCode] = MedicalCard.[ClientCode]) ON Personal.[DoctorCode] = MedicalCard.[DoctorCode]
GROUP BY 
   Personal.[DoctorCode];

INSERT INTO #ClientsCountForDoctor
EXEC nothing

CREATE TABLE #DeathCount (DoctorCode int, Deaths int)   

SELECT 
    Personal.[DoctorCode], Count(Clients.[ClientCode]) AS [Count-Код клиента]
FROM 
    Personal 
INNER JOIN 
    (Clients INNER JOIN MedicalCard ON Clients.[ClientCode] = MedicalCard.[ClientCode]) ON Personal.[DoctorCode] = MedicalCard.[DoctorCode]
GROUP BY 
    Personal.[DoctorCode], MedicalCard.[TreatmentResult]
HAVING 
    (((MedicalCard.[TreatmentResult])='Смерть'));

INSERT INTO #DeathCount
EXEC nothing
```

Then I want to use results. What should I EXEC?

```
SELECT 
   Personal.[DoctorName], 
   #DeathCount.Deaths/#ClientsCountForDoctor.Clients AS [DeathPercent]
FROM 
   (#ClientsCountForDoctor INNER JOIN Personal ON #ClientsCountForDoctor.[DoctorCode] = Personal.[DoctorCode]) 
INNER JOIN 
   #DeathCount ON Personal.[DoctorCode] = #DeathCount.[DoctorCode];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need is `Select Into` syntax. `It will create the table for you with the selected data inserted at the same time`. Then from the last query do a normal select using created tables

**Ex:**

```
SELECT col1,col2,..
INTO #temp          --Note: this temporary table will be created in the db
FROM yourTable
```

**Your queries:**

```
SELECT Personal.[DoctorCode], 
       Count(Clients.[ClientCode]) AS [Count-Код клиента]
INTO #ClientsCountForDoctor --NOTE

FROM Personal INNER JOIN 
 (Clients INNER JOIN MedicalCard ON Clients.[ClientCode] = MedicalCard.[ClientCode]) 
           ON  Personal.[DoctorCode] = MedicalCard.[DoctorCode]
GROUP BY Personal.[DoctorCode];


SELECT Personal.[DoctorCode], 
       Count(Clients.[ClientCode]) AS [Count-Код клиента]
#DeathCount  --NOTE

FROM Personal INNER JOIN 
  (Clients INNER JOIN MedicalCard ON Clients.[ClientCode] = MedicalCard.[ClientCode]) 
          ON Personal.[DoctorCode] = MedicalCard.[DoctorCode]
GROUP BY Personal.[DoctorCode], MedicalCard.[TreatmentResult]
HAVING (((MedicalCard.[TreatmentResult])='Смерть'));


SELECT p.[DoctorName], d.Deaths/c.Clients AS [DeathPercent]
FROM #ClientsCountForDoctor c INNER JOIN Personal p
     ON c.[DoctorCode] = p.[DoctorCode]
           INNER JOIN #DeathCount d 
     ON p.[DoctorCode] = d.[DoctorCode];
```

Comment: "Invalid column name" here: d.Deaths/c.Clients

Comment: Check your `select into queries`. Each temp table has two columns created. They are `[DoctorCode], [Count-Код клиента]`. I just optimised your last query as it was too hard to read.

Comment: It should be #DeathCount instead of d and #ClientsCountForDoctor  instead of c right? I try #DeathCount.[Count-Код клиента] and #ClientsCountForDoctor.[Count-Код клиента] and get the error "the multipart identifier could not be bound". Help plz.

Comment: I have removed unnecessary `( )`. should be okay now. check it now.